# Is there any book on Google App Engine for java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to start using **Google App Engine for java**. But i don't know, where to start.
Is the tutorial provided by google [ http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html ] enough ?
Also, please mention some good books on GAE [ java ] so that i can  <strike>download those from rapidshare or torrent</strike> buy those books and start reading them.

Comment: Do you already know Java? The tutorials will not show you how to write Java, they'll only show you how to interact with App Engine from your Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently reading Beginning Java Google App Engine from Apress. I think it's a good start for beginning with java on the app engine. The book also implement a project with GWT. The book give you more organized information then the getting started. Here what you'll learn:

- How to get up and running with App Engine, starting with the Google Plugin for Eclipse
- All about the development server for testing and developing your applications
- How to develop applications using Servlets & JSPs, Spring Framework, and open source Flash - - Remoting and Messaging servers
- How to leverage the datastore in your applications, including Persistence as a Service
- How to use Spring as a Service for transactions, data access, and more
- How to use Google Web Toolkit to create AJAX components to drive your web applications
- How to send email and instant messages (XMPP) from within your application
- How to increase performance of your apps by storing data in memory using the Memcache service

Comment: Thanks, i am going to start reading `Beginning Java Google App Engine from Apress`

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at "Programming Google App Engine" by Dan Sanderson (O'Reilly). That is for Python or Java.

Answer (score 5):

Google GAE-Java doc/tutorial is good enough.

There's a book by Apress "Beginning Java Google App Engine" that discussed specifically Java, GWT, JDO. I skimmed over it once while I was in my local bookstore and to be honest, you'll get the same amount of exposure to that of Google's doc/tutorial with extra commentary.

I prefer the straightforward (Google's) approach than the Apress.

Few things to mention:

- Google's tutorial/doc directed you to what some people might considered the "preferred" approach (using JDO instead of JPA) and explanations to why.
- AFAIK, Apress book doesn't teach you how to unit-test GAE-Java app (especially code that relies on GAE services)
- Sometime the Apress book would tell you to go to Google's tutorial (e.g.: how to implement paging)

Apress book is good only if you want to know how to integrate GAE project with other libraries like GWT, Spring, and Flex (not even Wicket). But these are just configuration issues that you can Google it.

Hope this help.

Ed

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the best price you can, or get it used.  Things are changing rapidly with GAE.

Answer (score 1):

I found Dan Sanderson's book on GAE very immersive and thoughtful. His treatment of the topic is in-depth and goes beyond hello world programs. I recommend this book for all those who want to learn GAE in Java in depth.

OTOH I found Beginning Java Google App Engine from Apress disappointing. I could not find anything in this book which I could not gather from Google I/O and Google articles.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial was sufficient to get me started.  I learned App Engine via the tutorials back before there were any books out.

Comment: (And yes, I walked 20 miles to school in the snow, uphill both ways)